# Can't exclude user interface state from commit in xcode

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode4.5, commit

I can't exclude user interface state file from commit.

Every time I'm trying to push to github it asks me to commit first and insert user interface state file into the changes (even if I didn't move the mouse or interface at all it still is shown to commit!).

I tried different methods, described in other similar topics. For example, I tried to add all possible cases of user interface into the .gitignore in root, like this:

```
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
UserInterface.xcuserstate
```

It didn't work.
I tried to clean the cache and reset git, didn't help.

Git status command says the following:  "modified:   .xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate"

And it looks like this 
[image]

Please help (it is driving me crazy)!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If those files are already committed, you need to remove them from the index before seeing your .gitignore file work.

```
git rm --cached *.xcuserstate
# or
git rm -r --cached project.xcworkspace
```

Answer (score 20):

To add on to VonC's answer after calling -rm you also have to commit and then push (do this in the terminal BEFORE touching Xcode or it's git tools again), that solved my problem.

So

```
git rm --cached *.xcuserstate
git commit -m "Removed cached files"
git push
```

Then you can touch Xcode again