# Can't exclude user interface state from git in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode5, gitignore

I'm having troubles with my .gitignore entry

```
*.xcuserstate
```

being ignored in Xcode 5.
The accepted answer to the similar question [Can't exclude user interface state from commit in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312775/cant-exclude-user-interface-state-from-commit-in-xcode) seems not to work. Maybe it's a difference between Xcode 4.5 and Xcode 5?

Here's what I did:

1. Committed every pending change via 'Commit' from the Xcode Source Control menu
2. Entered terminal command `git rm --cached *.xcuserstate`
3. Restarted Xcode (just to be sure)
4. Selected 'Commit' again from the Source Control menu.

The result is, that Xcode now still wants to commit a change to .xcuserstate: the 'D' (for deleted) next to it suggests that it wants to commit the change, that the .xcuserstate file has been deleted (or does 'D' mean 'deleted from git'?).

If now I decide to commit this 'delete' change, and after that hit 'Commit' again, everything is just like it was before my terminal command. Xcode keeps reporting changes to .xcuserstate ('M' next to the file) every time I'm committing something else.

What am I doing wrong?